# SQL Server compare

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `SavingsMaster`. This is some sample data from it:

```
LBrCode PrdAcctId                           ActToBalLcy
28      20060000000000020000000100000000    3010.78
```

and another table called `D010014`:

```
LBrCode PrdAcctId                           CblDate     Balance3
28      20060000000000020000000100000000    4/28/2015   3010.78
28      20060000000000020000000100000000    4/7/2015    3000
```

I want to select records where final balance in D010014 (orderby CblDate) which are not matching with SavingsMaster.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to get the most recent record from `d010014`.  Then a `left join` can be used to match the record.  The following returns the rows with no match, even those with no row in `d010014`:

```
select sm.*, d.Balance3
from SavingsMaster sm left join
     (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by lbrCode, PrdAcctId 
                                order by CblDate desc) as seqnum
      from d010014 d
     ) d
     on d.lbrCode = sm.lbrCode and d.PrdAcctId = d.PrdAcctId and
        d.seqnum = 1
where d.PrdAcctId is null or d.Balance3 <> sm.ActToBalLcy;
```

Note:  this may not work if the balances are stored as floating point numbers, because of rounding errors.  Instead of `<>`, you can use:

```
abs(d.Balance3 - sm.ActToBalLcy) > 0.001 -- or some threshold like this
```

Also, this assumes that both `lbrCode` and `PrdAcctId` are needed to match the tables.  If only one is needed, you can simplify the query by removing the logic for the other.

Comment: You meant to say instead of d.Balance3 <> sm.ActToBalLcy I can use abs(d.Balance3 - sm.ActToBalLcy) < 0.001?

Comment: you can't use row_number this way. When you join on seqnum = 1, you elliminate the rows from D010014 where balance3 and ActToBalLcy are identical in the latest row giving null instead of the latest not-matching row

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . This is a `left join` that chooses the most recent row from `d010014` in the `on` clause.  The `where` clause does the filtering.  There is no comparison to values in the `on`, so I'm not sure what your comment refers to.

Comment: you are picking the latest row from d010014. If that row has the same balance as SavingsMaster, that row will be elliminated. Your query is wrong

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . the question is "which are not matching with SavingsMaster."  This returns the rows where the last record in the second table **does not match** the record in the first table.  That is the question being asked.

Comment: and if the value of Balance3 match ActToBalLcy where seqnum = 1 this returns nothing from D010014 , because seqnum =1 is part of the condition

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . We are clearly interpreting the question differently.  I'm pretty sure this answers the question being asked.  Either that, or you don't understand what `left join` does.